# Find DISTINCT Missing SQL Dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by

I have script which returns all invalid dependencies in database. But this script returns many duplicates. So I want to see only `DISTINCT` results.

```
    /*
modified version of script from http://michaeljswart.com/2009/12/find-missing-sql-dependencies/
Added columns for object types &amp; generated refresh module command...
filter out user-define types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330521/find-broken-objects-in-sql-server
*/

SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) AS [this Object...],
        o.type_desc,
    ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
    + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name) AS [... depends ON this missing entity name]
    ,sed.referenced_class_desc
    ,case when o.type_desc in( 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' ,'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION' ,'SQL_TRIGGER' ,'VIEW')
          then 'EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule ''' + QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) + ''';'
          else null
       end as [Refresh SQL Module command]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies as sed
LEFT JOIN sys.objects o
            ON sed.referencing_id=o.object_id
WHERE (is_ambiguous = 0)
    AND (OBJECT_ID(ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
    + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)) IS NULL)
    AND NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT * 
        FROM sys.types 
        WHERE types.name = referenced_entity_name 
        AND types.schema_id = ISNULL(SCHEMA_ID(referenced_schema_name), SCHEMA_ID('dbo'))
       )
ORDER BY [this Object...],
[... depends ON this missing entity name]
go
```

This is script.

I tried to Add `GROUP BY [... depends ON this missing entity name]` But I get the following error:

> Invalid column name '... depends ON this missing entity name'.

I've tried to add aggregate functions to each column in result just for test, but still same error.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
    + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)`

Comment: @Matt, yes, `GROUP BY` helps. Always think GROUP BY by alias should work...

Comment: Did the `GROUP BY` work?

Comment: @Matt, seems like yes. Error no more is showed

Comment: Sorry demo you cannot use alias names in the group by clause.  This is a consequence of the [The Logical Processing Order](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/the-logical-processing-order-3/).

Comment: @destination-data nice explanation link :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP BY` the actual field names not the alias.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) AS [this Object...],
        o.type_desc,
    ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
    + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name) AS [... depends ON this missing entity name]
    ,sed.referenced_class_desc
    ,case when o.type_desc in( 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' ,'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION' ,'SQL_TRIGGER' ,'VIEW')
          then 'EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule ''' + QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) + ''';'
          else null
       end as [Refresh SQL Module command]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies as sed
LEFT JOIN sys.objects o
            ON sed.referencing_id=o.object_id
WHERE (is_ambiguous = 0)
    AND (OBJECT_ID(ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
    + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)) IS NULL)
    AND NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT * 
        FROM sys.types 
        WHERE types.name = referenced_entity_name 
        AND types.schema_id = ISNULL(SCHEMA_ID(referenced_schema_name), SCHEMA_ID('dbo'))
       )
GROUP BY ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '') + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '') + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '') + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)
ORDER BY [this Object...],
[... depends ON this missing entity name]
go
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an APPLY operator to access aliases earlier in the query, e.g. (look for oa.x oa.y oa.z)

```
SELECT
        o.type_desc, sed.referenced_class_desc
      , oa.x , oa.y , oa.z
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed
  LEFT JOIN sys.objects o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
  OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT
              ISNULL(QUOTENAME(sed.referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
            + ISNULL(QUOTENAME(sed.referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
            + ISNULL(QUOTENAME(sed.referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
            + QUOTENAME(sed.referenced_entity_name)                    AS x
          ,  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) 
            + '.' 
            + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id))                   AS y
          , CASE
                  WHEN o.type_desc IN ('SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE', 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION', 'SQL_TRIGGER', 'VIEW') 
                    THEN 'EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule ''' 
                      + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) 
                      + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) 
                      + ''';'
                  ELSE NULL
            END                                                        AS z
      ) AS OA
WHERE (is_ambiguous = 0)
      AND (oa.x IS NULL)
      AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  *
            FROM sys.types
            WHERE types.name = referenced_entity_name
                  AND types.schema_id = ISNULL(SCHEMA_ID(referenced_schema_name), SCHEMA_ID('dbo'))
            )
GROUP BY
        o.type_desc, sed.referenced_class_desc
      , oa.x , oa.y , oa.z
;
```