# SQL Server trigger reports 'inserted' table is missing

Tags: sql-server

I am running a script against a SQL Server 2016 database that creates various tables, views and triggers. This same script has been working against dozens of other servers but it is getting an error against this one particular server.

All of the triggers seem to be created but when I check for invalid objects it reports all of them as invalid. The really strange part is, it says the problem is the "inserted" table (or "deleted" table, depending on the trigger) is missing.

I am checking for invalid objects using this query:

```
SELECT 
    QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' 
        + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) AS ProblemObject,
    o.type_desc,
    ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
    + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name) AS MissingReferencedObject
FROM
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.objects o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
WHERE
    (is_ambiguous = 0)
    AND (OBJECT_ID(ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
    + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)) IS NULL)
ORDER BY
    ProblemObject,
    MissingReferencedObject
```

which I got from here

[Find broken objects in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330521/find-broken-objects-in-sql-server)

The triggers are "instead of" triggers against the views that then modify the underlying tables.  There is really nothing special about any of them.

Is there something wrong with my query and the objects aren't really invalid or is there something with the database?  I am running the script as the database owner so I don't think it is a permissions issue.

Thanks

Comment: You have found the problem with those types of validation queries. `inserted` and `deleted` are virtual tables, not actual tables, so queries that try to identify if they exist will fail unless they can correctly identify that the `inserted` table in this case is the virtual table, and not meant to be some actual table that someone named `inserted`.

Comment: But why has this exact query never been a problem before, even on other SQL 2016 servers?

Comment: Now THAT is a good question. Hmmm.... I ran this SQL Fragment against my local SQL Server instance, and I notice that 'inserted; and 'deleted' do not show up in the list of items to be validated.  Why does it show up in 2016 in this case? Is the DB encapsulated?  SELECT *
FROM
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.objects o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
WHERE type = 'TR'
ORDER BY 
 type_desc,
 referenced_entity_name

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what 'encapsulated' is.  What am I supposed to look for in this query?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, then it probably isnt.  In this query, do the inserted and deleted tables show up? Look through the list of the triggers.

Comment: I just had a thought. Its possible that the quoting rules are different on this server than on other servers. Are the table names inserted and deleted inside of quotes (single or double) or square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Run this query against the problem SQL Server, and against one where no problems are shown:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.objects o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
WHERE type = 'TR'
ORDER BY 
    type_desc,
    referenced_entity_name
```

If the inserted / deleted tables show up in one list but not the other, then there is some difference causing this. I'd check identifier quoting rules to start.

Comment: Inserted and deleted do show up in the problem database and not the others, but I can't seem to find out why.  All of the database properties (other than Auto Close) are the same.

Comment: This becomes a Microsoft question, I think. You might try dropping and recreating one trigger manually, and see if it still shows up, but inserted and deleted are considered temporary tables, and "Dependency information [shown by sys.sql_expression_dependencies] is not created or maintained for rules, defaults, temporary tables, temporary stored procedures, or system objects."