# Check Compiled views in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have more than 1000 views in my SQL Server database but some views have errors because the tables used in the views have been renamed, therefore I get errors, and that's fine.

My question is: I need to check which views are valid and can be successfully used.

Comment: who ever renamed a table without correcting all views and stored procedures needs to be fired on the spot

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330521/find-broken-objects-in-sql-server

Comment: Do you know what table(s) were renamed? If you do you can use SQL Search from redgate. It is a free tool that could help.

Comment: You can leverage some dynamic sql and sys.views as well. Bottom line is you are going to have to walk through this somewhat manually and figure out what is broken.

Comment: Might be worth going through all of the views anyway and adding `WITH SCHEMABINDING`. Stops any renames of tables/columns that the view depends on, so you can't end up in this situation again in the future.

Comment: I know what tables were renamed and it is around 4500 tables

Comment: I don't want to do it manually because the actual count of views are 8235

Answer (score 0):

In case you known what tables have been renamed and there only a few, you can search every object where the old tablename is used like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc,
       m.*
FROM   sys.sql_modules m
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%OLD_TABLE_NAME_HERE%';
```

if you dont know what tables have been renamed, you can try this script to find invalid objects, but be aware it can return false positives

```
select QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) AS ProblemObject,
       o.type_desc,
       ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
         + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name) AS MissingReferencedObject
from   sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
  left join sys.objects o on sed.referencing_id=o.object_id
where  (is_ambiguous = 0)
and  (OBJECT_ID(ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
       + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)
     ) IS NULL)
order by ProblemObject, MissingReferencedObject
```

EDIT
To get a list of all valid objects (valid meaning not referencing any non existing objects) all you need to do is convert the last IS NULL to IS NOT NULL like this

```
select QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) AS ProblemObject,
       o.type_desc,
       ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
         + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name) AS MissingReferencedObject
from   sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
  left join sys.objects o on sed.referencing_id=o.object_id
where  (is_ambiguous = 0)
and  (OBJECT_ID(ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
       + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)
     ) IS NOT NULL)
order by ProblemObject, MissingReferencedObject
```

Mind you this only list objects that do not refernce non existing objects, they might still be invalid for other reasons

EDIT
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME is not available in sql server 2005.
You can leave out that part in the query it will still work the only problem is that the schema name (eg dbo.) will be omitted from the result.
If all your objects are in the same schema that is not a problem off course

```
select QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) AS ProblemObject,
       o.type_desc,
       ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
         + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name) AS MissingReferencedObject
from   sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
  left join sys.objects o on sed.referencing_id=o.object_id
where  (is_ambiguous = 0)
and  (OBJECT_ID(ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
       + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)
     ) IS NOT NULL)
order by ProblemObject, MissingReferencedObject
```

Comment: I know what tables and i have the list but the tables are around 4500 and its too much.

Comment: Can you help me with something that i can get a list of successful views

Comment: @MuhammadSaadRoshan I have edited my answer. But these queries do not only list VIEWS but also other objects, please to not forget that when renaming tables not only views but also triggers and stored procedures can become invalid

Comment: Problem is OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME does not work in sqlserver 2005

Comment: OK I did not know that sorry

Comment: I seems that is you install SP4 on sql server 2005 this function would become available, but I cannot test this since I dont have sql server 2005

Comment: I made another edit in the answer, you can leave out the OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME