# Is there a "user_objects where status='INVALID'" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I'm trying to get all the invalid objects in SQL Server.

In ORACLE, I only need to do:

```
select * 
from user_objects 
where status = 'INVALID'
```

There is a similar way in SQL Server?

Thanks!

Comment: Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2330544/6167855), perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find broken objects in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330521/find-broken-objects-in-sql-server)

Comment: In oracle there is a view to the invalid objects, in sql apparently there's isn't... I'm new in stack overflow, but here: https://blog.devart.com/find-invalid-objects-in-your-databases.html i found the closest to my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching, actually in SQL SERVER there is not a VIEW or a TABLE with this invalids objects. The closest I found to get my doubts was in [this link.](https://blog.devart.com/find-invalid-objects-in-your-databases.html)

If it help, I'm happy to share! =)